# Error displayed int Clion "multiple definition"

Tags: c++, clion

```
using namespace std;

class Student{

public:

    int rollNumber;

    int age;

    static int totalStudents;

};

int Student :: totalStudents = 0;


int main() {

    cout<<Student :: totalStudents << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Why do I get this error in Clion? The code seems to work fine on other online IDEs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YccEa.png)

Here's the error message I'm getting :

CMakeFiles\OOPS2.dir/objects.a(Student.cpp.obj):Student.cpp:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `Student::totalStudents'

CMakeFiles\OOPS2.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\OOPS2.dir\build.make:115: OOPS2.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]:**  [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:75: CMakeFiles/OOPS2.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YccEa.png):  **[CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/OOPS2.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: OOPS2] Error 2

Comment: Please format your code and include the error message as text in the quesiton

Comment: Did you carefully read the first two lines of error messages?

Comment: Please make a [mre]. Especially include all the files mentioned in the error messages.

Comment: Just a wild guess, you are not including code files, are you?

Comment: You have `totalStudents` defined in both `main.cpp` and `Student.cpp`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are two files listed in your Makefile, namely Student.cpp and main.cpp (as stated in error message)? If they are within the same Makefile or project or linked or include/reference each other then no wonder.

Answer (score 1):

On the screenshot you compile two files `Student.cpp` and `main.cpp`. Seems they have duplicated code.